# Why can't my coldfusion cfc access a udf included in application.cfm?

Tags: logging, coldfusion, scope, cfc, application.cfm

I've got a logging function (can't use cflog) included in application.cfm and my .cfm pages can access this, but any components I use give me a "Variable LOGGER is undefined." error.

application.cfm

```
<cfinclude template="logging.cfm">
```

logging.cfm

```
<cffunction name="logger" >
 ...
</cffunction>
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

because the way components work is that a component can't see the "`variables`" scope outside of itself, and when you `<cfinclude>` your `logging.cfm`, it's including those functions into the page's variable scope. in order for your component to call those functions, you might do this:

```
<cfinclude template="logging.cfm">

<cfset request.logger = variables.logger>
```

and then in your `<cfcomponent>`, you could call `request.logger(whatever)`.

But honestly, this feels backwards to me. Instead, why not a `Logger.cfc` that contains a function named "log", and then when you want to log something, you just do:

```
<cfinvoke component="my.Logger" method="log" message="#mylogmessage#">
```

Comment: thanks that's clear, but yes the last part of your answer seems to have been missed out

Comment: I've made the missing part visible. +1 to the answer.